# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/movies/9/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am following a rails tutorial, I am using rails 3.2.3 and I have this error Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/movies/9/edit"

Here is my haml page:

%h2 Edit Movie

= form_tag edit_movie_path(@movie), :method => :put do

= label :movie, :title, 'Title'
  = text_field :movie, 'title'

= label :movie, :rating, 'Rating'
  = select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']

= label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On'
  = date_select :movie, :release_date

= submit_tag 'Save Changes'

Here is my controller:

def edit

```
@movie = Movie.find params[:id]
```

end

def update

```
@movie = Movie.find params[:id]
@movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie])
flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
```

end

and my routes:

movies GET    /movies(.:format)          movies#index

```
       POST   /movies(.:format)          movies#create
```

new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      movies#new
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) movies#edit

```
 movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#show

       PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#update

       DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#destroy
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial may be leading you astray.

It's telling you to have your form `PUT` to the edit path.

You really want to `PUT` to the normal movie path. An `update` is implied by the `PUT` verb.

Instead of:

```
= form_tag edit_movie_path(@movie), :method => :put do
```

Try:

```
= form_tag movie_path(@movie), :method => :put do
```

Indeed, you may want to find a different tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are trying to post (put) on the edit action which in your routes file is defined with a get (exactly the way the edit action it's supposed to be)

In a standard way you would want to post to either your create or update path, but if you want to send the form to edit, use method get or change your routes for the edit action to accept put